# Rails: Drop down with 'Add new' option which creates more form fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to have a drop down on a form. So for example a user is picking an equipment type. But if it is not in the dropdown I want there to be an option for 'Add New' and when this is clicked some more fields pop up that the user must fill in.

So essentially when the form is submitted it creates two new model objects: Equipment and EquipmentType.

Is this possible?

Comment: absolutely it is possible.  It will require basic JavaScript, and some css styling.  Are you using jquery ?

Comment: yeah. So there is no plugin to handle it?

Comment: The answer posted pretty much covers plugins.  Personally I would just   do it without resorting to a plugin OTHER than jquery-ui.  I'd assemble the functionality you want using the jquery-ui components.  I use ruby gems when appropriate for the back end,  but have never really liked JavaScript plugins, other than to observe what they do and borrow a technique here and there.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you exactly need, so I point you to two solutions:

1. When you clicks "Add new" and you need to fill more then one field.
   This is the standart situation for this gems: [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) and [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon).

   Example of how it looks: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?view=asciicast
2. When you clicks "Add new" and just want to add another option to
   `has_many` association. In this case you can transform the standart
   multiple select into that kind of behavior. Take a look at that
   question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867795/best-jquery-multiselect-plugin, there are a couple plugins for this.

   Example: http://odyniec.net/projects/selectlist/examples.html

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is still no gem for it. I assume you have two models, `Equipment`, and `EqipmentType`, each of them has `:name` and they are connected via `belongs_to/has_many` association.

My solution will add an `attr_accessor :new_equipment_type` to `Equipment`, which is populated after the form is submitted.

Then, it creates a new equipment type if needed and connects it to the equipment:

```
# app/models/equipment.rb
class Equipment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :equipment_type
  attr_accessible :name, :equipment_type_id, :new_equipment_type
  attr_accessor :new_equipment_type

  def new_equipment_type=(val)
    if equipment_type_id.blank?
      write_attribute(:equipment_type_id, EquipmentType.create(name: val).id)
    end
  end

end

# app/models/equipment_type.rb
class EquipmentType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :equipments
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

The form has a dropdown with existing equipment types and when a blank option is selected, new input is shown for a new equipment type name:

```
#app/views/equipments/_form.html.haml
= simple_form_for [@equipment] do |f|
  = f.input :name
  = f.association :equipment_type, include_blank: "Add new"
  = f.input :new_equipment_type, input_html: {value: "New equipment type name"}, wrapper_html: {style: "#{if @equipment.equipment_type_id.present? then 'display:none;' else '' end}"}
```

And finally javascript to show/hide the new equipment type field:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/equipments.js.coffee:
@showOrHideNewEquipmentTypeField = (drop_down) ->
  new_equipment_type = $(drop_down).closest('form').find('div.input[class*=new_equipment_type]')
  if $(drop_down).val()
    $(new_equipment_type).slideUp()
  else
    $(new_equipment_type).slideDown()

$ ->
  $('[name*=equipment_type_id]').change ->
    showOrHideNewCategoryField(@)
```

Comment: how do you ensure the new_equipment_type method is called upon submitting the form?